# Why are my brackets considered errors in my do-while and if statements?

Tags: c++, error-handling, while-loop, do-while, curly-braces

I have an assignment, where I have to count down in lyrics according to the number in user input (between 1 to 100). In the last set of lyrics, when the countdown gets to 1, it's supposed to change from `bottles` to `bottle`, then eventually 0.

Visual Studio is telling me I'm missing a `while` (last closing bracket) and a `;` (open bracket after `do (beerAmount - 1)` ), but no matter where I put the `;` where I think it makes sense, it wont run. I don't understand why it's telling me I'm missing a `while` statement. **My professor strongly recommended I use a `do-while` loop.**

An example of it sucessfully running would result with an output like this:

*imagine the user imputed `2` when prompted for how many bottles of beer*

```
2 bottles of beer on the wall. 2 bottles of beer. Take 1 down, pass it around.  1 bottle of beer on the wall.
1 bottle of beer on the wall. 1 bottle of beer. Take 1 down, pass it around.  0 bottles of beer on the wall.
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int beerAmount;
    int lessAmount = (beerAmount - 1);  
    do {
        cout << "Enter an amount of beers between 0 and 101: " << endl;
        cin >> beerAmount;
        if ((beerAmount > 0 && beerAmount < 101)) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Invalid amount! Please try again" << endl;
        }
    } 
    while (true); {
        do (beerAmount - 1) { //this bracket
            cout << beerAmount << " bottles of beer on the wall. " << beerAmount << " bottles of beer. Take " << beerAmount << " down, pass it around. " << lessAmount << " bottles of beer on the wall." << endl;
        }
        if ((beerAmount == 1)) {
            cout << beerAmount << " bottle of beer on the wall. " << beerAmount << " bottle of beer. Take " << beerAmount << " down, pass it around. 0 bottles of beer on the wall." << endl;
        }
        if (beerAmount == 0) {
            break;
        }
    } //this bracket
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `do (beerAmount - 1)` `do` doesn't have an argument.

Comment: I would advise you to really learn the syntax of statements before doing the assignments. Also your code indentation looks really messy and that makes it easy to miss mismatched braces.

Comment: This is explained in any beginner level [c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Perhaps you meant something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/3v9rq8qjE

Comment: Consider using a function to avoid code duplication (and always get the pluralization correct): https://godbolt.org/z/YKjd4xeMd

Answer (score 0):

### The syntax of the do-while-loop is incorrect.

It should be:

```
do {
    //code to repeat...
}
while(condition);
```

When the loop is fixed, you also need to remove the closing curly brace just before the return-statement since it prematurely ends the function block.